# Two Dimensional Arrays with BigDecimal in Java

Tags: java, arrays, enums, bigdecimal

I am getting compiler errors that seem to point at the semicolon at the end of two statements, and I have no idea how to fix the problem.  The goal is to take in values from an Enum Class in Java and use them in financial calculations with a two dimensional arrays.

```
public enum User
{
Mike("Mike", "User", 8000, 0.03, 15, 25),
Jim("Jim", "User", 12000, 0.05, 12, 30),
Jane("Jane", "User", 9000, 0.02, 18, 25),
Mary("Mary", "User", 18000, 0.09, 5, 30);
Bill("Bill", "User", 14000, 0.06, 8, 30);


private final String firstName;
private final String lastName; 
private final int annualDeposit;
private final double annualIntRate;
private final int yearsToDeposit;
private final int yearsToCalcInt;


User(String firstName, String lastName, int annualDeposit, double annualIntRate, 
int yearsToDeposit, int yearsToCalcInt)
{
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
this.annualDeposit = annualDeposit;
this.annualIntRate = annualIntRate;
this.yearsToDeposit = yearsToDeposit;
this.yearsToCalcInt = yearsToCalcInt;
}

public String getFirstName()
{
return firstName;
}

public String getLastName()
{
return lastName;
}

public int getAnnualDeposit()
{
return annualDeposit;
}

public double getAnnualIntRate()
{
return annualIntRate;
}

public int getYearsToDeposit()
{
return yearsToDeposit;
}

public int getYearsToCalcInt()
{
return yearsToCalcInt;
}

}
```

---

```
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Work
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

int[] annualDeposit = new int[5];
double[] intRate = new double[5];
int[] yearsToDeposit = new int[5];
int[] yearsToCalcInt = new int[5];

BigDecimal[][] accountBalance = new BigDecimal[5][30];
BigDecimal[][] principal = new BigDecimal[5][30];

int count = 0;
int yearsDeposit = 0;    

for (User user: User.values())
{
annualDeposit[count] = user.getAnnualDeposit();
intRate[count] = user.getAnnualIntRate();
yearsToDeposit[count] = user.getYearsToDeposit();
yearsToCalcInt[count] = user.getYearsToCalcInt();
count++;
}       

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{  
yearsDeposit = 0;          
for (int year = 0; year <= yearsToCalcInt[i]; year++)
{
if(yearsDeposit <= yearsToDeposit[i])
{
principal[i][year] += annualDeposit[i] + accountBalance[i][year];
BigDecimal accountBalance[i][year] = 
principal[i][year].multiply(intRate[i].add(BigDecimal.ONE).pow(year));

yearsDeposit++;   
}
else
{
principal[i][year] += accountBalance[i][year];
BigDecimal accountBalance[i][year] = 
principal[i][year].multiply(intRate[i].add(BigDecimal.ONE).pow(year));
}
}      
}


}
}
```

Comment: `Mary` ends with `;`...?

Comment: and, although off topic, it is not a good idea to make students as enum.

Answer (score 1):

`Mary` ends with a `;` which Java takes to mean that there are no more entries for the `enum`...

```
public enum User {

    Mike("Mike", "User", 8000, 0.03, 15, 25),
    Jim("Jim", "User", 12000, 0.05, 12, 30),
    Jane("Jane", "User", 9000, 0.02, 18, 25),
    Mary("Mary", "User", 18000, 0.09, 5, 30); <--- Culprit here...
    Bill("Bill", "User", 14000, 0.06, 8, 30);
```

Change it to `,` instead...

```
public enum User {

    Mike("Mike", "User", 8000, 0.03, 15, 25),
    Jim("Jim", "User", 12000, 0.05, 12, 30),
    Jane("Jane", "User", 9000, 0.02, 18, 25),
    Mary("Mary", "User", 18000, 0.09, 5, 30),
    Bill("Bill", "User", 14000, 0.06, 8, 30);
```

Nit Pick: Convention states that enum literals should be in uppercase

```
public enum User {

    MIKE("Mike", "User", 8000, 0.03, 15, 25),
    JIM("Jim", "User", 12000, 0.05, 12, 30),
    JANE("Jane", "User", 9000, 0.02, 18, 25),
    MARY("Mary", "User", 18000, 0.09, 5, 30),
    BILL("Bill", "User", 14000, 0.06, 8, 30);
```

See [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) for more details